# Auto expand a textarea using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I make a textarea automatically expand using jQuery?

I have a textbox for explaining the agenda of the meeting, so I want to expand that textbox when my agenda's text keep growing that textbox area.

Comment: i thik textarea is autoexpandable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Searching for the Ultimate Resizing Textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586931/searching-for-the-ultimate-resizing-textarea)

Comment: Please consider changing your question and removing the word "jQuery"

Answer (score 117, accepted):

<s>I have tried lots and
[this one is great.](http://javascriptly.com/examples/jquery-grab-bag/autogrow-textarea.html)</s> <sup>Link is dead. Newer version is [available here](https://github.com/ro31337/jquery.ns-autogrow). See below for old version.</sup> 
You can try by pressing and hold enter key in textarea. Compare the effect with the other auto expanding textarea plugin....

**edit** based on comment

```
$(function() {
   $('#txtMeetingAgenda').autogrow();
});
```

note: you should include the needed js files...

To prevent the scrollbar in the textarea from flashing on & off during expansion/contraction, you can set the `overflow` to `hidden` as well:

```
$('#textMeetingAgenda').css('overflow', 'hidden').autogrow()
```

---

**Update:**

The link above is broken. But you can still get the javascript files [here](https://github.com/jaz303/jquery-grab-bag/tree/master/javascripts).

Comment: if my textbox id is txtMeetingAgenda then how can i implement Auto textArea property in jquery

Comment: here click event is define or not

Comment: this is all about textarea but what about textbox.is this plugin also work for textbox?

Comment: this plugin doesn't work well, try autosize, it's *way* better

Comment: It works fine only one way when textarea is growing. But when you start deleting the text, it's not automatically reducing the height.

Answer (score 171):

If you dont want a plugin there is a very simple solution

```
$("textarea").keyup(function(e) {
    while($(this).outerHeight() < this.scrollHeight + parseFloat($(this).css("borderTopWidth")) + parseFloat($(this).css("borderBottomWidth"))) {
        $(this).height($(this).height()+1);
    };
});
```

See it working in a [jsFiddle I used to answer another textarea question here](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/m8Qk9/).

To answer the question of doing it in reverse or making it smaller as text is removed: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/m8Qk9/280/)

> And if you do want a plugin

[@Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7173/jason) has designed one [here](https://github.com/ultimatedelman/autogrow)

Comment: I had to remove + parseFloat($(this).css("borderTopWidth"))+ parseFloat($(this).css("borderBottomWidth")), else it infinitely loops with a textarea styled with bootstrap

Comment: jQuery-less version:
`if (this.clientHeight < this.scrollHeight) {
    this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + 'px';   
}`

Comment: @metakungfu Well instead of just downvoting, maybe you can help improve the answer. I don't have any way of testing apple crap atm and safari for windows was discontinued a long time ago. So I can't really do anything to determine why it wouldn't work. Code-wise, there's nothing wrong with this solution. Are you sure it's the code that's breaking and not safari breaking in jsfiddle? safari is pretty picky and fiddle did just go through a major update. Mayeb you can open dev con and provide some more detail?

Comment: @SpYk3HH how can I get this to work for a textarea which is appended to the DOM please?

Comment: @TimMarshall Read up on event delegation for dynamic events [**here**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). jQuery recently, or sometime in last couple years, i only noticed recently, made a pretty nice tut site for better understanding jQuery. What you're asking about is simple event delegation on dynamic elements. That is to say, you use a static selector, such as `$(document)`, and then delegate the event to a dynamic selector (one that will select whatever is later loaded), such as `.on('click', 'textarea', func`.

Comment: also needs textarea overflow-y set to hidden to prevent flashing scroll

Comment: If I want to remove the added rows, the enlarged size of the textbox remains the same, is it possible that it can also automatically resize back?

Answer (score 33):

## CSS-only solution:

This requires Chrome version `123` minimum and is using [`field-sizing` property](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui/#field-sizing)

```css
textarea {
  field-sizing: content;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<textarea>
Here is a
Multiline
Textarea
</textarea>
```

## jQuery-based solution:

Below demo utilizes jQuery for event binding, but it's not a must in any way. 
(*no IE support - IE doesn't respond to **rows** attribute change*)

```js
$(document)
  .one('focus.textarea', '.autoExpand', function() {
    var savedValue = this.value
    this.value = ''
    this.baseScrollHeight = this.scrollHeight
    this.value = savedValue
  })
  .on('input.textarea', '.autoExpand', function() {
    var rows, minRows = this.getAttribute('data-min-rows') | 0;
    this.rows = minRows
    rows = Math.floor((this.scrollHeight - this.baseScrollHeight) / 16)
    this.rows = minRows + rows
  });
```

```css
textarea {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: padding-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 6px solid #556677;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class='autoExpand' rows='3' data-min-rows='3' placeholder='Auto-Expanding Textarea'></textarea>
```

### See in CodePen

---

Comment: This is a great solution. Very smooth, and can autoshrink as added benefit. But pardon my curiosity: could you share a little on why you make use of setTimeout rather than directly call autosize() ?

Comment: because the code must wait a little for the letter you typed to be printed inside the textarea and therefor change the textarea's dimensions

Comment: Thanks a lot for your pointers. I will add http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful as a good resource on how setTimeout helps even with the 0 millisecond value.

Comment: I see, the solution is broken when the text is copied (CTRL+V) from any source. While, if the text is manually typed - this is awesome and very smooth.

Comment: @Jason - please elaborate in what way doesn't it work? 404 / you see nothing / codepen error / you see everything but the javascript does not work / have console errors / etc.

Comment: the textarea doesn't grow when i add too much text, so yea the JS doesn't work

Comment: @Jason - please write in what browser / OS. you cannot just say "it doesn't work", because for me it works on IE/Chrome/Firefox (WIN7) versions dated to the end of 2013.

Comment: latest chrome, windows 7. i can say "it doesn't work" because it doesn't. you can't say "it works on my machine" because that's meaningless. i'll even give you steps to help repro the problem: 1) click your demo link. 2) add a bunch of jibberish. 3) note how textarea does not grow to compensate for text extending beyond its scroll height.

Comment: I see what you mean. you don't press the ENTER key...I will fix this. thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @Jason - fixed it. works for modern browsers except IE.

Comment: Breaks/collapses on keydown on refocus after a blur event. If repeated additional white lines are added each time to the end of the textarea.

Comment: @Sir.NathanStassen - should be better now, changed the `focus` from `on` to `one` so calculations will occur once.

Comment: @vsync: how would you modify for multiple text areas?  I.e. you have textarea1 and textarea2 and you want to allow both to grow?

Comment: This should be the top answer! I posted a question based on that if anyone is interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29930300/force-resizement-when-importing-text-from-file

Comment: Trying to learn from this answer.. What is the difference between rows and this.rows?
How would you explain the line - var minRows = this.getAttribute('data-min-rows')|0, rows;

Comment: Also, how would you write it in a directive so that can be used in several locations?

Comment: @vsync in your pen you divide by 17, is that that the line height?

Comment: @AllyMurray - I went now and updated it to 16 since it seem to give better result. and yes, that is the expected line height

Comment: This solution worked really well for me, but I found that dividing by 20 `rows = Math.ceil((this.scrollHeight - this.baseScrollHeight) / 20); ` prevented any extra rows from being added, which eliminated unusable whitespace.

Answer (score 27):

You can try this one

```js
$('#content').on('change keyup keydown paste cut', 'textarea', function () {
        $(this).height(0).height(this.scrollHeight);
    }).find('textarea').trigger("change");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <textarea>How about it</textarea><br />
  <textarea rows="5">111111
222222
333333
444444
555555
666666</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: if you want to get the scrollHeight from $(this), you can use $(this).prop('scrollHeight'); instead ;)

Comment: it blinks every line break

Answer (score 21):

- [**Auto Growing Textareas**](http://plugins.jquery.com/autogrow/)
- [**jQuery Autosize**](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/)

Comment: Autosize plugin is best

Answer (score 11):

Thanks to SpYk3HH, I started with his solution and turned it into this solution, which adds the shrinking functionality and is even simpler and faster, I presume.

```
$("textarea").keyup(function(e) {
    $(this).height(30);
    $(this).height(this.scrollHeight + parseFloat($(this).css("borderTopWidth")) + parseFloat($(this).css("borderBottomWidth")));
});
```

Tested in current Chrome, Firefox and Android 2.3.3 browser.

You may see flashes of the scroll bars in some browsers. Add this CSS to solve that.

```
textarea{ overflow:hidden; }
```

Comment: it doesn't work good at all :/ every character i type, it adds height.

Comment: It works perfect for me! There's definitely nothing in the simple code to do what you say it does.

Comment: yeah I see it now, your code must have the line which sets the height to 30 initially. this is probably an un-needed ilne because it forces the developer to tweak the code, instead of the code understand and adapt to the textarea,

Comment: That's incorrect. The developer does not need to tweak the code. Setting the height to 30 is required and it works for everything. The user never sees that happen. That is how it's able to shrink the textarea. The code does understand and adapt to the textarea. That is the whole point.

Comment: You are correct. demo page: http://jsbin.com/ObEcoza/2/edit (setting the height to `1px` seems to be better)

Comment: Nice one. I was also confused by the height setting to 30px and commented that out initially. But it works with the line just fine!

Comment: However I just noticed the original solution works better. Your solution seems to have problems with textareas larger than windows size. Every keyup on such textareas seems to scroll whole window up and down. Also the initial (after the first keyup) textarea resize is noticeable.

Answer (score 10):

To define a auto expandable textarea, you have to do two things:

1. ***Expand*** it once you click Enter key inside it, or type content more than one line.
2. And ***shrink*** it at blur to get the actual size if user has entered
   white spaces.(*bonus*)

Here is a **handmade function** to accomplish the task.

**Working fine with almost all browser ( < IE7 )**. Here is the method:

```
    //Here is an event to get TextArea expand when you press Enter Key in it.
    // intiate a keypress event
    $('textarea').keypress(function (e) {  
       if(e.which == 13)   {   
       var control = e.target;                     
       var controlHeight = $(control).height();          
      //add some height to existing height of control, I chose 17 as my line-height was 17 for the control    
    $(control).height(controlHeight+17);  
    }
    }); 

$('textarea').blur(function (e) {         
    var textLines = $(this).val().trim().split(/\r*\n/).length;      
    $(this).val($(this).val().trim()).height(textLines*17);
    });
```

[HERE](https://17path.wordpress.com/2013/01/08/resize-textarea-on-enter-pressed/) is a post about this.

Answer (score 6):

I've used the [Textarea Expander](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/textarea-expander/index.html) jQuery plugin before with good results.

Comment: A text box (input text element I presume) isn't multiline.  Use a textarea but style it appropriately - rows, columns etc, and then use the auto-grow plugin as above.

Answer (score 4):

Everyone should try this jQuery plugin: [xautoresize-jquery](http://code.google.com/p/xautoresize-jquery/downloads/list). It's really good and should solve your problem.

Comment: This one gave me the best results and is also easy to implement.

Answer (score 4):

```
function autosize(textarea) {
    $(textarea).height(1); // temporarily shrink textarea so that scrollHeight returns content height when content does not fill textarea
    $(textarea).height($(textarea).prop("scrollHeight"));
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("input", "textarea", function() {
        autosize(this);
    });
    $("textarea").each(function () {
        autosize(this);
    });
});
```

(This will not work in Internet Explorer 9 or older as it makes use of the `input` event)

Comment: in my project, as I am rendering whole things in the page by Jquery and typescript, your solution was the only way that I could solve my problem 
thanks

Answer (score 3):

I just built this function to expand textareas on pageload.  Just change `each` to `keyup` and it will occur when the textarea is typed in.

```
// On page-load, auto-expand textareas to be tall enough to contain initial content
$('textarea').each(function(){
    var pad = parseInt($(this).css('padding-top'));
    if ($.browser.mozilla) 
        $(this).height(1);
    var contentHeight = this.scrollHeight;
    if (!$.browser.mozilla) 
        contentHeight -= pad * 2;
    if (contentHeight > $(this).height()) 
        $(this).height(contentHeight);
});
```

Tested in Chrome, IE9 and Firefox.  Unfortunately Firefox has [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=576976) which returns the incorrect value for `scrollHeight`, so the above code contains a (hacky) workaround for it.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed a few bugs in the answer provided by Reigel (the accepted answer):

1. The order in which html entities are replaced now don't cause unexpected code in the shadow element. (The original replaced ">" by "&ampgt;", causing wrong calculation of height in some rare cases).
2. If the text ends with a newline, the shadow now gets an extra character "#", instead of having a fixed added height, as is the case in the original.
3. Resizing the textarea after initialisation does update the width of the shadow.
4. added word-wrap: break-word for shadow, so it breaks the same as a textarea (forcing breaks for very long words)

There are some remaining issues concerning spaces. I don't see a solution for double spaces, they are displayed as single spaces in the shadow (html rendering). This cannot be soved by using &nbsp;, because the spaces should break. Also, the textarea breaks a line after a space, if there is no room for that space it will break the line at an earlier point. Suggestions are welcome.

Corrected code:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.autogrow = function (options) {
        var $this, minHeight, lineHeight, shadow, update;
        this.filter('textarea').each(function () {
            $this = $(this);
            minHeight = $this.height();
            lineHeight = $this.css('lineHeight');
            $this.css('overflow','hidden');
            shadow = $('<div></div>').css({
                position: 'absolute',
                'word-wrap': 'break-word',
                top: -10000,
                left: -10000,
                width: $this.width(),
                fontSize: $this.css('fontSize'),
                fontFamily: $this.css('fontFamily'),
                lineHeight: $this.css('lineHeight'),
                resize: 'none'
            }).appendTo(document.body);
            update = function () {
                shadow.css('width', $(this).width());
                var val = this.value.replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
                                    .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
                                    .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
                                    .replace(/\n/g, '<br/>')
                                    .replace(/\s/g,'&nbsp;');
                if (val.indexOf('<br/>', val.length - 5) !== -1) { val += '#'; }
                shadow.html(val);
                $(this).css('height', Math.max(shadow.height(), minHeight));
            };
            $this.change(update).keyup(update).keydown(update);
            update.apply(this);
        });
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 3):

Code of SpYk3HH with addition for shrinking size.

```
function get_height(elt) {
    return elt.scrollHeight + parseFloat($(elt).css("borderTopWidth")) + parseFloat($(elt).css("borderBottomWidth"));
}

$("textarea").keyup(function(e) {
    var found = 0;
    while (!found) {
        $(this).height($(this).height() - 10);
        while($(this).outerHeight() < get_height(this)) {
            $(this).height($(this).height() + 1);
            found = 1;
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you see my answer before yours?

Comment: Your solution does not suit me, there was some error, I don't remember which.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me better:

```js
$('.resiText').on('keyup input', function() { 
$(this).css('height', 'auto').css('height', this.scrollHeight + (this.offsetHeight - this.clientHeight));
});
```

```css
.resiText {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    resize: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="resiText"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

People seem to have very over worked solutions...

**This is how I do it:**

```
  $('textarea').keyup(function()
  {
    var 
    $this  = $(this),
    height = parseInt($this.css('line-height'),     10),
    padTop = parseInt($this.css('padding-top'),     10),
    padBot = parseInt($this.css('padding-bottom'),  10);

    $this.height(0);

    var 
    scroll = $this.prop('scrollHeight'),
    lines  = (scroll  - padTop - padBot) / height;

    $this.height(height * lines);
  });
```

This will work with long lines, as well as line breaks.. grows and shrinks..

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  $('textarea[name="mytextarea"]').on('input', function(){
    $(this).height('auto').height($(this).prop('scrollHeight') + 'px');
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

**this worked for me perfectly well**

```
 $(".textarea").on("keyup input", function(){
            $(this).css('height', 'auto').css('height', this.scrollHeight+ 
       (this.offsetHeight - this.clientHeight));
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using the plugin posted by Reigel please be aware that this will disable the undo functionality in Internet Explorer (go give the demo a go).

If this is a problem for you then I would suggest using the [plugin](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/textarea-expander/index.html) [posted by](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2948239/3408) @richsage instead, as it does not suffer from this problem. See the second bullet point on [Searching for the Ultimate Resizing Textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586931/searching-for-the-ultimate-resizing-textarea) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this jquery function that seems to work.

You need to specify min-height in css though, and unless you want to do some coding, it needs to be two digits long. ie 12px;

```
$.fn.expand_ta = function() {

var val = $(this).val();
val = val.replace(/</g, "&lt;");
val = val.replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
val += "___";

var ta_class = $(this).attr("class");
var ta_width = $(this).width();

var min_height = $(this).css("min-height").substr(0, 2);
min_height = parseInt(min_height);

$("#pixel_height").remove();
$("body").append('<pre class="'+ta_class+'" id="pixel_height" style="position: absolute; white-space: pre-wrap; visibility: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; width: '+ta_width+'px; height: auto;"></pre>');
$("#pixel_height").html(val);

var height = $("#pixel_height").height();
if (val.substr(-6) == "<br />"){
    height = height + min_height;
};
if (height >= min_height) $(this).css("height", height+"px");
else $(this).css("height", min_height+"px");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also the very cool [`bgrins/ExpandingTextareas (github)`](https://github.com/bgrins/ExpandingTextareas) project, based on a publication by [Neill Jenkins](http://nmjenkins.com/) called [**Expanding Text Areas Made Elegant**](http://alistapart.com/article/expanding-text-areas-made-elegant)

Answer (score 1):

I wanted animations and auto-shrink. The combination is apparently hard, because people came up with pretty intense solutions for it. I've made it multi-textarea-proof, too. And it isn't as ridiculously heavy as the jQuery plugin.

I've based myself on vsync's answer (and the improvement he made for it), http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vlIwj is the codepen for my improvement.

HTML

```
<textarea class='autoExpand' rows='3' data-min-rows='3' placeholder='Auto-Expanding Textarea'></textarea>
```

CSS

```
body{ background:#728EB2; }

textarea{  
  display:block;
  box-sizing: padding-box;
  overflow:hidden;

  padding:10px;
  width:250px;
  font-size:14px;
  margin:50px auto;
  border-radius:8px;
  border:6px solid #556677;
  transition:all 1s;
  -webkit-transition:all 1s;
}
```

JS

```
var rowheight = 0;

$(document).on('input.textarea', '.autoExpand', function(){
    var minRows = this.getAttribute('data-min-rows')|0,
        rows    = this.value.split("\n").length;
    $this = $(this);
    var rowz = rows < minRows ? minRows : rows;
    var rowheight = $this.attr('data-rowheight');
    if(!rowheight){
      this.rows = rowz;
      $this.attr('data-rowheight', (this.clientHeight  - parseInt($this.css('padding-top')) - parseInt($this.css('padding-bottom')))/ rowz);
    }else{
      rowz++;
      this.style.cssText = 'height:' + rowz * rowheight + 'px'; 
    }
});
```

Comment: Note: i've noticed it sometimes works better with box-sizing: content-box. I'm not entirely sure why though, it should process padding correctly :(

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of answers for this but I found something very simple, attach a keyup event to the textarea and check for enter key press the key code is 13

`keyPressHandler(e){`
`if(e.keyCode == 13){`
 `e.target.rows = e.target.rows + 1;`
`}`
`}`

This will add another row to you textarea and you can style the width using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you're trying to accomplish this using Knockout... here's how:

In page:

```
<textarea data-bind="event: { keyup: $root.GrowTextArea }"></textarea>
```

In view model:

```
self.GrowTextArea = function (data, event) {
    $('#' + event.target.id).height(0).height(event.target.scrollHeight);
}
```

This should work even if you have multiple textareas created by a Knockout foreach like I do.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Solution:

HTML:

```
<textarea class='expand'></textarea>
```

JS:

```
$('textarea.expand').on('input', function() {
  $(this).scrollTop($(this).height());
});
$('textarea.expand').scroll(function() {
  var h = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (h > 0)
    $(this).height($(this).height() + h);
});
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/7wsnwbzg/

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution:

html:

```
<textarea class="auto-expand"></textarea>
```

css:

```
.auto-expand {
    overflow:hidden;
    min-height: 80px;
}
```

js (jquery):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("textarea.auto-expand").focus(function () {
        var $minHeight = $(this).css('min-height');
        $(this).on('input', function (e) {
            $(this).css('height', $minHeight);
            var $newHeight = $(this)[0].scrollHeight;
            $(this).css('height', $newHeight);
        });
    });       
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with pure JS

```
function autoSize() {
  if (element) {
    element.setAttribute('rows', 2) // minimum rows
    const rowsRequired = parseInt(
      (element.scrollHeight - TEXTAREA_CONFIG.PADDING) / TEXTAREA_CONFIG.LINE_HEIGHT
    )
    if (rowsRequired !== parseInt(element.getAttribute('rows'))) {
      element.setAttribute('rows', rowsRequired)
    }
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Samb102/cjqa2kf4/54/

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I ended up using. I wanted an inline solution, and this so far seems to work great:

```
<textarea onkeyup="$(this).css('height', 'auto').css('height', this.scrollHeight + this.offsetHeight - this.clientHeight);"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function autoResizeTextarea() {
  for (let index = 0; index < $('textarea').length; index++) {
    let element = $('textarea')[index];
    let offset = element.offsetHeight - element.clientHeight;
    $(element).css('resize', 'none');
    $(element).on('input', function() {
      $(this).height(0).height(this.scrollHeight - offset - parseInt($(this).css('padding-top')));
    });
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/nanachi1/pen/rNNKrzQ

this should work.

Answer (score 0):

@Georgiy Ivankin made a suggestion in a comment,
I used it successfully :) -- , but with slight changes:

```
$('#note').on('keyup',function(e){
    var maxHeight = 200; 
    var f = document.getElementById('note'); 
    if (f.clientHeight < f.scrollHeight && f.scrollHeight < maxHeight ) 
        { f.style.height = f.scrollHeight + 'px'; }
    });
```

It stops expanding after it reaches max height of 200px

Answer (score 0):

Old question but you could do something like this:

html:

```
<textarea class="text-area" rows="1"></textarea>
```

jquery:

```
var baseH; // base scroll height

$('body')
    .one('focus.textarea', '.text-area', function(e) {
        baseH = this.scrollHeight;
    })
    .on('input.textarea', '.text-area', function(e) {
        if(baseH < this.scrollHeight) {
            $(this).height(0).height(this.scrollHeight);
        }
        else {
            $(this).height(0).height(baseH);
        }
    });
```

This way the auto resize will apply to any textarea with the class "text-area". Also shrinks when text is removed.

jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/rotaercz/46rhcqyn/

Answer (score 0):

Simple jQuery solution:

```
$("textarea").keyup(function() {
    var scrollHeight = $(this).prop('scrollHeight') - parseInt($(this).css("paddingTop")) - parseInt($(this).css("paddingBottom"));

    if (scrollHeight > $(this).height()) {
        $(this).height(scrollHeight + "px");
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<textarea rows="2" style="padding: 20px; overflow: hidden; resize: none;"></textarea>
```

***Overflow*** should be ***hidden***. ***Resize*** is ***none*** if you do not want to make it resizable by mouse.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the textarea's height to its scrollHeight on all events that change its potential size:

```
function setTextareaResponsive(id) {
   adjustTextareaHeight(id);

   $(window).on("resize", function() {
      adjustTextareaHeight(id);
   });

   $("#" + id).on("change input", function() {
      adjustTextareaHeight(id);
   });
}

function adjustTextareaHeight(id) {
   // set height to 1, so scrollHeight is related to linecount, not original textarea size
   $("#" + id).height(1);
   $("#" + id).height(document.getElementById(id).scrollHeight);
}
```

I personally like it better, when the height is not padded by the extra height (usually 12px) that scrollHeight provides.
That's why I like to set the height to the number of lines multiplied by the lineHeight, in which case the function adjustTextareaHeight would look like this:

```
function adjustTextareaHeight(id) {
   var textarea = document.getElementById(id);

   // set height to 1, so scrollHeight is related to linecount, not original textarea size
   $("#" + id).height(1);
   var lineHeight = parseInt(getComputedStyle(textarea).lineHeight)
   var numberOfLines = Math.floor(textarea.scrollHeight / lineHeight)
   $("#" + id).height(lineHeight * numberOfLines);
}
```

Comment: This sounded cool, but it yields a `Uncaught ReferenceError: adjustTextAreaHeight is not defined`

Comment: Thanks for the input, there was a camelCase typo in the first adjustTextareaHeight function-call in setTextareaResponsive method.