# Textarea width auto resize

Tags: jquery, textarea, width, resizable

I want to auto resize the textarea width when I write inside it, with a max-width, like this code do for the input.
http://jsbin.com/ahaxe
it's possible?

Comment: maybe using em in your wisth. it represents the width on an M. will not be very precise but it could work.

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948230/auto-expand-textarea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/buM6M/1/

html:

```
<textarea id="t1" style='min-width:100px;min-height: 100px'>

</textarea>

 <div id="d1" style='max-width:200px;min-height:20px;display: none'>

</div>
```

​

js code :

```
  $("#t1").live({
keyup: function(e){

    $("#d1").text($(this).val());
    $(this).css("width", $("#d1").css("width"));
    $(this).css("height", $("#d1").css("height"));
}
});​
```

Set the dimensions of the div and textarea as per your requirement .

Answer (score 4):

have you tried these may be these can help you

http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize

http://www.technoreply.com/autogrow-textarea-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

use jquery autogrow plugin.

download [autogrowtextarea.js](http://www.technoreply.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/jquery.autogrowtextarea.js) and add to script

and add this css in head:

```
#id_of_textarea
{
height:auto;
width:width_of_textarea_you_want
}


$(function() {
$('#id_of_textarea').autogrow();
});
```

for avoiding scroll:

```
$('#id_of_textarea').css('overflow', 'hidden').autogrow()
```

Comment: where did you take `autogrow` from?