# Increase the textarea height (without the scroll bar) dynamically as the user keeps typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My application has a textarea (html) field with the following css

```
.textareaCss{overflow: auto;width:500px; height:15px; margin:0; padding:5px; margin-top:4px; margin-bottom:5px; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; border:#d9d9d9 solid 1px;color: #999;}
```

Now the effect is, if the user's comment grows such that the content typed is occupying more space than what height of 15px can accomodat, then the scroll bar appears and user cant see the first line as shown

[image]

Is it possible that the height of the textarea grows such that the whole content is always seen. 
PleaseNote: Anyhow the limit of characters is 1000.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948230/auto-expand-textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948230/auto-expand-textarea)

Comment: I created a plugin a while back that does what you need and a lot more: https://github.com/ajcrites/jquery.supertextarea -- it works marginally well

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://www.impressivewebs.com/demo-files/textarea-auto-resize/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is as follows
1. Download the pluging "autogrow.js" [Autogrow js from GitHub](https://github.com/jerryluk/jquery.autogrow)

And then add it to your code and give the reference respectively.

Then add the code as below

```
$(function() {
   $('#txtMeetingAgenda').autogrow();
});
```

Comment: @GabrielRyanNahmias - ya, but i can only after 23 hours itseems. so i will do it later....Anyhow thanks for your guidance... :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use jQuery to accomplish this. I think the change event will work for you. All you have to do is reset the height on change.

For example:

```
$('.textareaCss').on('keyup', function(){
    $(this).css('height', '100%');
});
```

I haven't tested this, but it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Probably "onkeyup", not "onchange", if anything

Comment: I would agree, I wasn't sure if onchange fired after each keystroke or only after focus left. Key up is the better option here. Response editted.

Comment: @Mike Thanks for the quick reply, (not sure if i am missing something in your answer) But this way the textarea gets expanded as soon as you click on it instead of as on the user reaches a new line. Anyhow i got the answer via a plugin called "autogrow.js" [https://github.com/jerryluk/jquery.autogrow] Code is as follows, 1. Give teh reference to the plugin and add the code as follow , **$(function() { $('#txtMeetingAgenda').autogrow(); });**

Comment: Just adding a valid link to the aforementioned repo (the last one includes the ending bracket): https://github.com/jerryluk/jquery.autogrow