# HTML TextArea resize automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to have a text area which is always as big as the text in it. So the page can be scrolled and in the text area cannot be scrolled.
Here's what I did until now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {height: 100%;}
textarea {
border: none;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
line-height: 44px;
font-family:Helvetica;
font-size: 17pt;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
background-image:url('linedBack@2x.png');
outline: none;
resize: none;
}
textarea.vert { resize:vertical; }
</style></head><body>
<textarea id="InputTextArea" placeholder="placeholder"></textarea>
</body></html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a textarea with auto-resize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize)

Comment: I created a package for this if you are using react: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fluid-textarea

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Resizing TeaxArea based on the content line number. Here's a [DEMO](http://cssdeck.com/labs/eiwcpf9l)

JS

```
function resizeTextarea (id) {
  var a = document.getElementById(id);
  a.style.height = 'auto';
  a.style.height = a.scrollHeight+'px';
}

function init() {
  var a = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
  for(var i=0,inb=a.length;i<inb;i++) {
     if(a[i].getAttribute('data-resizable')=='true')
      resizeTextarea(a[i].id);
  }
}

addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
```

HTML

```
<textarea id="InputTextArea" placeholder="placeholder" onkeyup="resizeTextarea('InputTextArea')"></textarea>
```

Comment: This is answer is concise, but the end result isn't very smooth. The text jumps quite a bit before the input area expands, leading to a less than ideal user experience. Chris G.'s answer gives a much better solution

Comment: "onkeydown" event is much efficient to resize textarea instantly. Thank you.

Comment: @shubhra Why we need add `a.style.height = 'auto';` on function `resizeTextarea` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using AngularJS, you can do :

```
<textarea ng-keyup="ctl.handleTextAreaHeight($event)"></textarea>
```

With this in your controller :

```
this.handleTextAreaHeight = function (e) {
  var element = e.target;

  element.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  element.style.height = 0;
  element.style.height = element.scrollHeight + 'px';
};
```

Comment: This is the best answer I've found after scouring everywhere. Easily adaptable to pure js, no plugins, no jquery needed.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone still needs this, for what it's worth, here's mine in pure js. But first, you may check this one:
[Auto expand a textarea using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948230/auto-expand-a-textarea-using-jquery)

```
    var textAreas = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
    try {
        taLength = textAreas.length;
        for (i=0; i < taLength; i++) {
            var taId = textAreas[i].id;
            document.getElementById(taId).addEventListener('input', function(e) {
                e.target.style.height = "auto";
                    //This makes your textarea back to its original size. So you can replace it with any size you want it to have e.g. "120px"
                    //You may need some logic if you have multiple taxtareas with different original sizes
                e.target.style.height = e.target.scrollHeight+'px';
            });
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        window.alert(err);
    }
```

I used shubhra's answer to build that one. It is smooth and the scrollbar won't appear.

Answer (score 2):

If someone need a solution for Vue.js. Here is a vue directive to do a auto resizing text area. Just register directive globally once and you can use it for any textarea

```
Vue.directive('resizable', {
    inserted: function (el) {
        el.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
            e.target.style.height = "auto";
            e.target.style.height = e.target.scrollHeight + 'px';
        });
    }
});
```

html is easy, just put v-resizable attribute in textarea

```
<textarea v-resizable></textarea>
```

Special thanks to AniMir! I am using his input event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Just setting `height = scrollHeight` misses the goal when `box-sizing: border-box` is set. Here is a solution with a fix for that and which allows the textarea to shrink again.

```js
// auto resize the textareas
document.querySelectorAll("textarea").forEach(function (el) {
  el.addEventListener("input", function () {
    var cs = window.getComputedStyle(this);
    // reset height to allow textarea to shrink again
    this.style.height = "auto";
    // when "box-sizing: border-box" we need to add vertical border size to scrollHeight
    this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight + parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue("border-top-width")) + parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue("border-bottom-width"))) + "px";
  });
});

// compat window.getComputedStyle: IE9
// compat NodeList.forEach: No IE (but not necessary here)
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
textarea { width: 20%; }
#a { padding: 1em; }
#b { padding: 0; }
#c { max-height: 7em; }
#d {
  border-top: 10px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 10px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="a">1em padding</textarea>
<textarea id="b">0 padding</textarea>
<textarea id="c">max-height: 7em</textarea>
<textarea id="d">10px vertical borders</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            <textarea
               id="newComm"
               class="form-control"
               name="comment"
               placeholder="Some text"
               cols="30"
               :rows="rowsHeight"
               wrap="soft"
               v-model.trim="newCommText"
               @input="changeRows"
               :style="'resize: none; overflow: hidden; line-height: '+lineHeight+'px;'"
        ></textarea>

    setup() {
    
    const newCommText = ref(null)
    const rowsHeightStart = ref(5)
    const rowsHeight = ref(rowsHeightStart.value)
    const lineHeight = ref(25)
    function changeRows (event) {
        rowsHeight.value = event.target.value.split("\n").length > rowsHeightStart.value ? event.target.value.split("\n").length : rowsHeightStart.value
    }

    return {
         rowsHeight, lineHeight, newCommText,
        changeRows
    }
```