# How do I expand a new line for textarea when i press enter?

Tags: html

Suppose i have a textarea with the size of a normal textbox, how do i make it stretchable when i press enter or crtl+enter to make a new line for user to type.

For example, i type something in textarea in the first line, then i press enter and the textarea will expand a new line for me to enter data.

```
<td>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="description[]">
        <?php echo $row[ 'description']; ?>
    </textarea>
</td>
```

Above is the textarea that i mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use javascript. Specifically, you could use a javascript framework called jQuery. Check out this answer: [Auto expand a textarea using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948230/auto-expand-a-textarea-using-jquery)

Comment: If it can be done using jQuery, it can be done using javascript

Comment: @dc5 Correct. I didn't mean to imply that jQuery itself was required. I'll edit my answer to be more clear.

Comment: if it can be done using javascript, it can be done in less time/lines of code with jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You could try some jQuery:

```
$("textarea").keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) //13 is the ASCII code for ENTER
        {
            var rowCount = $(this).attr("rows");
            $(this).attr({rows: rowCount + 5});
        }
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5346855/2716915

This work for me :)                 

Though it's a long code, but i guess i understand the workflow.Thank to you all anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively - you could use a div with contenteditable set true.

```
<td>
  <div id="description[]" contenteditable="true">
    <?php echo $row['description']; ?>
  </div>
</td>
<input name="description[]" type="hidden" value="">
```

Then add a JS function to the form submit (assuming this is for a form) that sets the value of the hidden input to the inner text/content of the div

```
function updateText() {
  content = document.getElementById('description[]').textContent || document.getElementById('description[]').innerText;
  document.querySelector('[name="description[]"]').value = content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this auto grow jQuery plugin - https://github.com/akaihola/jquery-autogrow

Answer (score 0):

I used like this:

Jquery:

```
$('#parent-block-for-textarea').on('keyup', 'textarea.autoexpand', function(ev) {
        var t = ev.target;
        t.style.height = 'auto';
        t.style.height = (t.scrollHeight) + 'px';
});
//this also works on dynamically added textarea.
```

HTML:

```
<textarea class="autoexpand"></textarea>
```

Without using jquery:

```
<textarea onkeyup="this.style.height='auto';this.style.height=(this.scrollHeight)+'px'"></textarea>
```