# How to create dynamic resize for textarea with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have several textarea elements in my html/php page. However, I need these textareas to resize dynamically. At the basic level, it need to expand when a user presses the enter key. How could I use javascript to make this happen? Any pointers are well appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto expand a textarea using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948230/auto-expand-a-textarea-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a basic implementation:

HTML:

```
<textarea id="a"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
var t = document.getElementById("a");
t.style.height = "80px";
t.onkeyup = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        t.style.height = parseInt(t.style.height) + 30 + "px";
    }
}
```

This is meant as something to start with.

[Link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/an9X2/2/)

Comment: Not really adjustable for different fonts etc.