# Increase textarea's height with text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can a textarea adapt it's height while inserting text?

I want to hide the textarea's borders, so that users feel they'r typing in an unlimited space.

(The textarea's height should be increased by height of one line when a new line starts)

One way I guessed, is to; copy all texts into a div with same width on each keystroke, then measure the height of the div, then set the div's height for textarea.

One problem I noticed, is scroll bars width that should be subtracted from main width, and on different devices we have 0 to 16px variable scroll bar width..., any suggestions?

Comment: You're sure you're not looking for content editable ?

Comment: @adeneo so is this an HTML5-only feature? Not yet...

Comment: Then there should be a thousand how-to's on how to autoexpand a textarea

Comment: http://www.impressivewebs.com/textarea-auto-resize/ might be of some use?

Comment: Correction: **this** seems to do exactly what you're talking about. http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto expand a textarea using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948230/auto-expand-a-textarea-using-jquery)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t7w7uf05/

Comment: @dfsq You deleted your answer? why!? that was working just as I wanted.

Comment: @mknadler yes that is a very nice plugin. most of what I found had bugs on first test drives.

Answer (score 0):

Here is What you want 
First: html here is the text area with id : ta

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="10" id="ta">
    </textarea>
```

And here is the jquery code which works as follows:
which increases the height (the rows number) of the text area each time you get into the last line

```js
  $('#ta').keypress( function(){
                    var rows=$('#ta').attr('rows');
                    var text=$('#ta').val();
                    var lines=text.split('\n');
                    if(lines.length==rows){
                        rows++;
                        $('#ta').attr('rows',rows);
                    }
                });
```

And this css just for hide the border of the textarea so the user feels that he/she writes in the page

```css
#ta{
      border: 0;
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can easily achieve what you're trying to do using **[elastic.js](http://unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/)**, it's a simple one-line solution.

```js
$('#note').elastic();
```

```css
textarea#note {
 width:100%;
 display:block;
 resize: none;
 border: none;
}
textarea:focus {
 outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://jquery-elastic.googlecode.com/svn-history/r37/trunk/jquery.elastic.js"></script>
<textarea id="note">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</textarea>
```

Comment: It scrolls now, without any texts added!

Comment: @webinan Not quite sure what you mean by that. Albeit I've edited the above snippet and you might want to check it again.