# Textarea height increase based on content height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need increase the text area height based on content. if user type the content it automatically increase. and if delete the content it need reduce the height.

Comment: Try a search on Google.

Comment: you can search on google ...you can find any jquery plugin . check this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948230/auto-expand-a-textarea-using-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes i got the answer, its work fine.

```
<textarea onkeyup="textAreaAdjust(this)" placeholder="Add a new answer" rows="1"></textarea>


 <script type="text/javascript"> 
                     function textAreaAdjust(o) {  
                     o.style.height = "1px";     o.style.height = (25+o.scrollHeight)+"px"; }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var observe;
if (window.attachEvent) {
    observe = function (element, event, handler) {
        element.attachEvent('on'+event, handler);
    };
}
else {
    observe = function (element, event, handler) {
        element.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
    };
}
function init () {
    var text = document.getElementById('text');
    function resize () {
        text.style.height = 'auto';
        text.style.height = text.scrollHeight+'px';
    }
    /* 0-timeout to get the already changed text */
    function delayedResize () {
        window.setTimeout(resize, 0);
    }
    observe(text, 'change',  resize);
    observe(text, 'cut',     delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'paste',   delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'drop',    delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'keydown', delayedResize);

    text.focus();
    text.select();
    resize();
}
</script>
<body onload="init();">
<textarea rows="1" style="height:1em;" id="text"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/salunkheganesh07/jbxwuym7/)

Reference [Creating a textarea with auto-resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize)

Answer (score 1):

you can use [jquery autogrow](http://plugins.jquery.com/autogrow/) pluing

Code :

```
 $('textarea').autogrow({onInitialize: true});
```

Note :  you need to include autogrow plugin file in to page