# Disable TextArea Horizontal Scrolling Jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll, textarea

I'm working within a child row.  I've created a text box via a textarea command within jQuery (seen below):

```
<td style="width: 370px;">
    <textarea rows = "5" style="width: 300px;"></textarea>
```

Here's the issue: I can't figure out how to disable horizontal scrolling and make it drop down to the next line when I reach the end of the text box.  So how do I disable horizontal scrolling?  I want vertical scrolling to be enabled so that the textarea doesn't get bigger, because it can't change size.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This does not appear to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948230/auto-expand-a-textarea-using-jquery , in fact, the question seems to be asking the exact opposite.

Comment: @saluce Thank you! I totally agree!  Is there any way to remove the duplicate flag?  I feel like people will ignore the question because of the flag...

Comment: It's already in the reopen queue...as people review the queue, they'll make a determination whether they agree or not.  Enough votes to reopen will remove the duplicate flag.  Too many "Leave Closed" votes will leave it closed and remove it from the queue.

Comment: The code you've provided does just what you're asking for in Chrome and FF.

Comment: @j08691 I forgot to mention that the client only uses Internet Explorer... (Yeah, I know, it makes complete sense to only use the worst browser in existence)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this simple code

```js
$("textarea").on("keydown keyup", function(){
    if(this.scrollHeight > $(this).outerHeight())
        $(this).height(this.scrollHeight);
});
```

```css
textarea {
  resize: vertical; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
```