# Why does my no-submit (HtmlButton) still submit?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, sharepoint-2010

I want to dynamically make rows, which exist all along but are at first hidden, visible.

I've tried the client-side (jQuery) route, but have had problems with that.

I would prefer going down the server-side (C#) road, and I thought I had found the way to accomplish it based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926250/how-can-i-make-a-sharepoint-textbox-input-type-text-dynamically-multiline) and this code:

```
HtmlButton btnAddFoapalRow = null;
. . .       
btnAddFoapalRow = new HtmlButton();
btnAddFoapalRow.Attributes["type"] = "button";
btnAddFoapalRow.InnerHtml = "+"; 
btnAddFoapalRow.ID = "btnAddFoapalRow";
btnAddFoapalRow.ServerClick += new EventHandler(btnAddFoapalRow_Click);
this.Controls.Add(btnAddFoapalRow);

private void btnAddFoapalRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ShowNextFoapalRow();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        String s = String.Format("Exception occurred: {0}", ex.Message); // TODO: Log this somewhere
    }
}

//// This only works the first time, because it causes the page to be reloaded, setting foapalRowsShowing back to 2
private void ShowNextFoapalRow()
{
    switch (foapalRowsShowing)
    {
        case 2:
            foapalrow3.Visible = true;
            foapalRowsShowing = 3;
            break;
        case 3:
            foapalrow4.Visible = true;
            foapalRowsShowing = 4;
            btnAddFoapalRow.Disabled = true;
            break;
    }
}


foapalrow3 = new HtmlTableRow();
foapalrow3.ID = "foapalrow3";
foapalrow3.Visible = false;
. . .
foapalrow3 = new HtmlTableRow();
foapalrow3.ID = "foapalrow3";
foapalrow3.Visible = false;
```

...but no go - the first time the second row is made visible, but a subsequent mashing of the "+" HtmlButton does not make the third row visible. And stepping through the code, I see why: the page *is* being submitted each time I mash the button, adn thus the initial code runs again, setting the number of rows visible back to two, and always making row3 visible (never row4).

This is what it looks like after mashing the button, no matter how many times I mash the button (one more row should be added, but it never is):

[image]

Row 1, BTW, is the column caption row; row 2 is the single row that is visible by default; row3 and row4 exist, but are not visible at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
btnAddFoapalRow.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return false;");
```

Comment: It's still stuck on only adding a second row. It refuses to add more after that.

Comment: Try using the edited version where I added your event handler instead of using the default onclick.

Comment: Yes, the edited version allowed it to work one time (before that, not at all).

Comment: Try this instead.
OnServerClick="return false;"

Comment: Actually sorry, I just realized. You can't prevent post back because you're calling a server script. It's receiving a response from the server. Your best option would be to do what I mentioned before using the onclick event and use client side instead. Make sure you remove the btnAddFoapalRow.ServerClick

Comment: Just wanted to point out another option is to use view states. So you can store the variable server side. The first link shows how to save and the second shows how to load.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227551(v=vs.85).aspx https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228048(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I am trying the client-side route, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30948026/why-does-this-jquery-cause-all-my-jquery-to-fail/30948065

Comment: Alright. Try OnClientClick="return false;" and let me know how that goes.

Comment: Do you mean like this: btnAddFoapalRow.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick", "return false;"); 
?

Comment: You will need to go into the aspx page of your windows forms.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It's not a Windows forms; this is a Sharepoint (ASP.NET) project.