# position div below text in textarea jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to position div below the text in textarea. So if I'm typing here, the div should be in the line below and so on...

any ideas how to get this text position to place div below it?

what I did just gets the div position, not the text.

```
var offset = $('#comment').offset();

var x_pos = offset.left;
var y_pos = offset.top;

  $("#display").css({
        top: x_pos,
        left: y_pos
  });
```

html:

```
<textarea id=comment>how to position #display always below this text? (even if I press enter)</textarea>

<div id=display></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/krxz4ogg/

Comment: Please include relevant html in question itself. Questions should be self contained so both current and future readers can review your issue without going off site

Comment: Do you want it below the text, in the text area? or below the entire text area completely?

Comment: @Chizzle below the text in the textarea, if it is possible...

Comment: Requires putting the text into another container and constantly checking height. Suggest looking into auto size scripts for textareas and setting value of another textarea on every key stroke...then adjust your div based on that container height. Or auto size your textarea and leave div below it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it if you have a fixed height on the div which you want to appear below your textarea text.

JS expandable texarea taken from [@SpYk3HH's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10080841/2868359).

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u2q3gw7x/

```js
$("#MyExpandingTextArea").keyup(function(e) {
  //  this if statement checks to see if backspace or delete was pressed, if so, it resets the height of the box so it can be resized properly
  if (e.which == 8 || e.which == 46) {
    $(this).height(parseFloat($(this).css("min-height")) != 0 ? parseFloat($(this).css("min-height")) : parseFloat($(this).css("font-size")));
  }
  //  the following will help the text expand as typing takes place
  while ($(this).outerHeight() < this.scrollHeight + parseFloat($(this).css("borderTopWidth")) + parseFloat($(this).css("borderBottomWidth"))) {
    $(this).height($(this).height() + 1);
  };
});
```

```css
#MyExpandingTextArea {
  padding-bottom: 6em;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1em;
}
#MovingDiv {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 3em;
    width: 3em;
    margin-top: -4em;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="myTextArea" id="MyExpandingTextArea"></textarea>
<div id="MovingDiv">
  &nbsp;
</div>
```

If you do not want the effect of the entire textarea expanding, consider wrapping the text area in a div with a fixed height and `overflow: hidden;`

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to detect the bottom of the text for default textarea – try using autosize plugins for textarea (something like [this](https://github.com/jackmoore/autosize/tree/master)), so it has the height of the text – probably the most simple solution because you won't actually need to position the div after that – it will always be just under the text without any magic.