# textarea padding issue with changing height

Tags: html, css

I have a simple textarea, like below:

http://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/469/

What I want to do is the following:

1. If there is no text in the input, have the height of the textarea be 50px.
2. If there is text in the input, change the height of the textarea to `auto`, but keep the minimum height of `50px`. The height of the textarea shouldn't change as long as there is 1 line of text in the textarea.

How would I do this?

```js
$(document).on('input', 'textarea', function(event) {
  var el = $(this);

  if (el.val()) {
    el.addClass('active');
  } else {
    el.removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
}
textarea {
  font-family: "Arial";
  width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea placeholder="Enter some text..."></textarea>
```

Comment: Set min-height to be 50px

Comment: here you go [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10080841/932540)

Comment: @danny3b That solution has an odd scrollbar glitch in Chrome where the scrollbar will appear for a split second and then disappear.

Comment: add `overflow:hidden;` or `resize:none;` or both to your textarea. (http://jsfiddle.net/uuxeshgr)