# Why does a DOJO tools text area control break my forms

Tags: django, dojo, django-comments

Hi I'm using django comments in one of my apps. I customized the comments framework to fit my needs. Everything works properly until I use dojo to make the textarea for the comments expandable http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/form/Textarea.html#dijit-form-textarea. After adding the script the form throws an error after submitting: this field is required. So it seems django doesn't recognize the textarea as part of the form anymore.

in my template I use the standart comment tags:

```
{% render_comment_form for event %}
{% render_comment_list for event %}
```

When I'm adding the dojo script, the textarea gets expandable, but the form doesn't pass it's value anymore.

```
dojo.require("dijit.form.Textarea");

dojo.ready(function(){
    var textarea = new dijit.form.Textarea({
        name: "id_comment",
        style: "width:200px;"
    }, "id_comment");
});
```

dojo adds a bunch of classes to the textarea so that it looks like following. But it still got it's id and it's still a textarea isn't it?

```
<textarea autocomplete="off" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode,containerNode,textbox" name="id_comment" class="dijitTextBox dijitTextArea dijitExpandingTextArea" style="overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: auto; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; width: 200px; height: 36px;" tabindex="0" id="id_comment" widgetid="id_comment" value="" rows="1"></textarea>
```

After reading the answers for this question: [Searching for the Ultimate Resizing Textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586931/searching-for-the-ultimate-resizing-textarea). I thought this might the best way to go but unfortunatly it's not.
I'm wondering if it's just me. Is there a way to get this right or should I use a different method to make the field expandable.

## Edit

with dojo the post looks like that:

```
content_type    cylebrations.image
csrfmiddlewaretoken 24827190efbb5b7793aeadaf8276beed
honeypot    
id_comment ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
object_pk   4
post    Post
security_hash   8a091cfbf1e309627369069d4f71c21b33843a85
timestamp   1335209980
```

without dojo:

```
comment eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
content_type    cylebrations.image
csrfmiddlewaretoken 24827190efbb5b7793aeadaf8276beed
honeypot    
object_pk   4
post    Post
security_hash   e02d8261f528cfc0f22ee30ced820cfbb80715bc
timestamp   1335210114
```

Comment: Could you intercept (using Firebug) the post data when you submits  comment? Is it there? Specifically look for if it is present, and its value is not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dojo overwrites the name of the textarea. I called it id_comment, instead of just comment. After changing that the post looks just fine and everything works like it should:

```
    dojo.require("dijit.form.Textarea");

    dojo.ready(function(){
        var textarea = new dijit.form.Textarea({
            name: "comment",
            style: "width:200px;"
    }, "id_comment");
});
```